# Cron expression to run job on specific date

Tags: cron

I need to run a job only once on `1st June, 2015 at 10 pm`. I think cron expression would be

```
0 0 22 1 6 ? 2015
```

Is the above correct? Or should it be `0 0 22 1 6 * 2015`?

Answer (score 0):

I think both are correct but if you see the description of placeholder `0 0 22 1 6 ? 2015` is better.

> *("all values") - used to select all values within a field. For example, "" in the minute field means *"every minute".
>
> ? ("no specific value") - useful when you need to specify something in
>   one of the two fields in which the character is allowed, but not the
>   other. For example, if I want my trigger to fire on a particular day
>   of the month (say, the 10th), but don't care what day of the week that
>   happens to be, I would put "10" in the day-of-month field, and "?" in
>   the day-of-week field. See the examples below for clarification.

Copied from the [tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)

Answer (score 0):

The correct one is only:

```
0 0 22 1 6 ? 2015
```

That's because **?** character must be present either in **day of month** or **day of week** field.

As stated in the documentation (**notes** section at the the very end):

> Support for specifying both a day-of-week and a day-of-month value is
>   not complete (you must currently use the '?' character in one of these
>   fields).

Good luck!